# Black Translucent Navigation Bar + MKMapView -> Setting map center is not visually correct

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, mkmapview

I have a Map View in a Navigation Controller under translucent black navigation, status and search and toolbars.

The actual height of the map includes the area below these bars.

The **+** left accessory button makes the map center on the Pin.

[image: Photo1] [image: Photo2]

The left image is before the map is centered to the pin's coordinates.

The right one is when the map in centered to the pin's coordinates.

The problem is that the center should be the center of the visible map area and not the whole map area. (which causes the pin to not appear in the center of the map.

Is there some offset or boundary setting I can do so the Map View will center correctly?

Comment: You could set your mapView to have the size of the visible area. Is there any specific reason to have the map go under the navigation bar?

Comment: :D    use opaque status bar and navigation bars, They will not overlap the Map . otherwise you can also change the frame of map by leaving space in Top position of the view on which you add the map.

Comment: I meant BlackNavigationBar and BlackStatusBar

Comment: Actually I want the map to be visible under the bars. it gives the user a feeling of larger map. is there some way I can intercept 'Set center' and/or 'Set Region' events/messages and change it before it is rendered..?

Comment: there are delegate methods for region change events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can overlay a transparent UIView (tView) for your visible map area (below navbar), get his point, calculate offset you need and setRegion again. (I guess you're using setRegion to center the map):

```
CGPoint currentPoint = [mapView convertCoordinate:myPin.coordinate toPointToView:self.view];
CGRect tFrame = [tView frame];
tFrame.origin.y = currentPoint.y - tFrame.size.height;
tFrame.origin.x = currentPoint.x - (tFrame.size.width/2);

MKCoordinateRegion newRegion = [mapView convertRect:tFrame toRegionFromView:self.view];
[mapView setRegion:newRegion animated:YES];
```

You should double check the tFrame so you can set it with the best values for your application.